# Collapse a menu when clicked outside the menu, but keep it open when clicked inside

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a popup menu with JQuery.  This menu shows when a certain element is clicked, and of course, when the same element is clicked again, it collapses. 
Now what I want, is that after this menu has been opened up, when the user clicks anywhere on the web page, the menu should close.  I am using the following code to accomplish this.

```
<script>
$(document).on('click',function(){

$('#div-header-submenu').collapse('hide');
```

});

What is happening now, is that when the user clicks anywhere on the web page, including the menu it-self, the menu closes down. So even if you tried to access the sub-menu inside the (#div-header-submeu), it would open the sub menu, but it will collapse the main menu.
Any ideas how to fix this situation?  Just to re-iterate, I need the #div-header-submenu to remain open when clicked inside the main menu, but collapse, if clicked anywhere outside.

Here is the Fiddle complete markup of the menu
https://jsfiddle.net/ozbk3kLs/

Thanks,

Comment: Can you add your HTML markup and rest of jQuery that shows/ hides the menu..

Comment: Just added link to the fiddle. It is standard bootstrap with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hy,
@Dhaval Chhenda answer should work. 
Another way of thinking is to wrap all the page content in a

`<div id="main">...</div>
<menu>...</menu>`

with you menu outside of it. And then call the `on('click')` method on main tag as shown here : https://api.jquery.com/click/

that will give you something like

html :

`<body>
  <div id=main>
    Content
  </div>
 <menu>
   menu 
 </menu>
</body>`

javascript:

`$( "#main" ).click(function() {
  $('#div-header-submenu').collapse('hide');
});`

css:

`menu {
   z-index: 100;
}`

z-index should be topped to be sure that it's on top of the layout.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Also, you could have fun doing it in full css :p

Comment: How can I do it in css?

Comment: In css it's a bit tricky: you have to create a checkbox with a label who will cover the main div and play with the inheritance (~) attribute. But you can't do this if you have links in the main div cause the layout will be on the top of the layout :).

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class='menu'></div>



    $('body').on('click',function(){
       if(!$(this).hasClass('menu'))
       $('#div-header-submenu').collapse('hide');
    });
```

Comment: can you share your url, in fiddle it looks like a crap

Comment: It's not live yet. It's on my local system.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a not selector because right now your condition itself is " click anywhere on the document" so you may try something like this

```
$("body:not(#div-header-submenu").on('click',function(){

$('#div-header-submenu').collapse('hide');
});
```

you may try this and see what happens

Comment: Hi Dhaval,
It's not working. I mean, it does not close the menu whether you click inside the dive or outside it.

Comment: ideally when the menu is opened you should have a class attached to it dynamically and then when you take that class away from it , it should close..click event on the open button should add a class like open and when its clicked outside then that class should be taken off

Comment: Can you please elaborate with an example?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of connecting the click event to the entire document, you could connect the click to an element inside the body (see example below).

As long as your header-submenu (when opened) is placed 'on top' of that element  (think in layers), it will only 'record' clicks 'outside' of you header-submenu. So clicks inside your header-submenu won't fire your closing function.

Very basic example of what I mean:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner"></div>
  <div id="element"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Airrudi/awndqe1t/

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, you're saying that the click should be connected to any div inside the body?

Comment: I've added a basic jsfiddle of what I mean